# Increase textarea size of an input in HTML without CSS

Tags: html

What I want to do is increase the size of the text area inside the input tag. I looked it up on google and all I was getting were solutions for the textarea tag and not the input text area.

```html
<input type="textarea" name="skills" placeholder="list the skills you require here" required>
```

I want the text area to be bigger in both width and height. Is there a possible way to do this without using CSS

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: "Is there a possible way to do this without using CSS" — Why do you object to using the presentation language of the web to describe the presentation of something on your webpage?

Comment: `type="textarea"` — There is no textarea type for the input element. Do you mean `type="text"`? Use a [validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/).

Comment: Altough `<input>` ignores rows attribute, you can take advantage of the fact, that `<textarea>` doesn't have to be inside `<form>` tags, but still be a part of a form by referencing form id. Also there is not `textarea` input type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the rows and the columns and get the derired width and height for your textarea.Also remove type="textarea" and just type at the beginning of the element textarea.Example show below:

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="100" name="skills" placeholder="list the skills you require here"  style="resize:none" required>
```

Comment: Ah yeah that's it.  Will it still act as an input though?

Comment: Yeah because the textarea is an input that can hold multiple lines.You can use the input type="text" if you want an one line text and modify the size with an inline style by configuring the height and the width of the element.                                                                                           <input type="text" name="skills" placeholder="list the skills you require here"  style="height:250px;width:240px">